# Atom Editor Next Line Shortcut

Tags: html, tags, atom-editor

I added a package to the Atom code editor that closes HTML tags for me. This feature is included in many code-editors, so it isn't Atom-specific.

For example, I type

```
    <h1>
```

and it conveniently changes the line to

```
    <h1></h1>
```

and **places my cursor between the two tags.**

This is where the dilemma occurs: **My cursor is placed between the words and the closing tag, and I wish to go to the next line.** Moving my hand to the mouse and clicking to the end of the line and then pressing enter is out of the question, especially with long documents where this phenomenon occurs hundreds, if not thousands of times.

Is there any way, perhaps a keyboard shortcut that skips to the end of the line, to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Atom, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows/Linux) will make a new line and go there, skipping past whatever is presently on the line.

Comment: If the line is very long, Ctrl + L is also useful.

Comment: not working in my macOS. where can I check the shortcut settings in Atom?

Answer (score 3):

You can just push the end button. Mine is located above my backspace key, but it might be with the number pad if you have a separate number pad.

Comment: Hmm, mine is above the number keypad. Pressing it would force me to take my hands off of the home row. But I admit, it is better than using the mouse. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you add the same element over and over again, you could copy & paste it. And for the sake of an empty element you could copy & paste something like `<br />` (you can even leave out the space, I just like to add them to make self-closing tags easier to identify).

PS: empty headlines? shame on you!